# Save audio file from app to iPad/iPhone library

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, save, audioformat

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for most of the day, but I haven't been able to find much help. We have this multimedia app that allows users to view pictures, videos, and music/ringtones about the particular subject. I know you can save images using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and you can save a video file using `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`. But I can't figure out how to allow the user to save an audio file. All the files are stored within the app, so its not like I'm trying to stream or download them from the internet. Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official SDK only allows you to retrieve information with `MPMediaLibrary`, no write access.

Comment: This is correct.  If you'd like Apple to implement write access for the media player library, you should file a bug at http://radar.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. So in order to listen to the clips, they will have to go through the app... there are no workarounds?

Comment: What a bummer... Thanks for the help.